# How to create custom donation amount using Payapl client side REST-API

Tags: javascript, paypal, scripting

I'm following the client side [Client Side Rest API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/client-side-REST-integration/) to create a donation button. The amount to charge is static in the code. I was able to pass in a variable after prompting the user to click a button to enter the amount, however, that is incredibly clunky and a default value is needed to prevent the PayPal window from closing as soon as it's opened if no values was entered.

```
// payment() is called when the button is clicked
        payment: function(data, actions) {
            // Make a call to the REST api to create the payment
            return actions.payment.create({
                payment: {
                    transactions: [
                        {
                            amount: { total: promptMe2(), currency: 'USD' }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            });
        },
```

You can see that I have the var `donationAmount`. That is set by default to a value. However, it can be changed by the user with:

```
<script>
var donationAmount = 16.11;

function promptMe(){
    donationAmount = parseFloat(prompt("How much would you like to donate?"));
    while (Number.isNaN(donationAmount)){
        alert("Invalid number, try again!");
        donationAmount = parseFloat(prompt("Amount to donate?"));
    }
    donationAmount = donationAmount.toFixed(2);
}
```

I tried to call `promptMe()` in place of the `donationAmount` variable (with an added return statement of donationAmount of course) and found that the page would just spam my error message for an invalid amount. When I hardcoded the value in it worked just fine. When I took the error checking out, it didn't even prompt me, it just instantly closed the paypal window. I was able to trigger an alert("Hello"); but that is pretty useless, I need to be able to accept user input and then pass it to Paypal.